# Array Unique not displaying some array after execution

Tags: php, arrays, unique

I'm using array_unique() to remove a duplicate value but it gives me an error when the value comes from a string then converted using explode, and values not displaying correctly

I'm using http://phptester.net/ to test

```
$email = 'general@t.com,info@t.com,info@t.com,jaa@t.com';

$emailList = array_unique(array_filter(array_map('trim',explode(',',$email))));

for($i = 0; $i < count($emailList); $i++){
    echo $emailList[$i];
}
```

Comment: Either use `foreach()` to loop over the array entries, or do an `array_values()`  to re-index them.... because you've removed the entry with a key of `2`, leaving keys `0`, `1` and `3`

Comment: @MarkBaker on what exact order should i do it?

Comment: After you've done the array_unique() that actually removes element #2 from the array: `$emailList = array_values(array_unique(array_filter(array_map('trim',explode(',',$email)))));`

Comment: @MarkBaker make than into an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it like this :

```
$email = 'general@t.com,info@t.com,info@t.com,jaa@t.com';

$emailList = (array_map('trim',explode(',',$email)));

$result = array_unique($emailList);
var_dump($result);
```

In case you want to print the array values, using for-loop, you can do like this:

```
$email = 'general@t.com,info@t.com,info@t.com,jaa@t.com';

$emailList = (array_map('trim',explode(',',$email)));

$result = array_unique($emailList);

for($i = 0; $i < count($emailList); $i++){
    if( $emailList[$i]!=null)
       echo $emailList[$i];
}
```